# Realm.io is not setting up on macos

Tags: node.js, npm, realm

I am trying to setup realm.io on my mac machine. 
node version is 8.11.3 and npm version is 5.6.0
I am getting following [errors](https://gist.github.com/nomantintash/d3aecb7d36ceeaf2d73ffc28f6ea68cb).

Comment: What version are you trying to work against?

Comment: Looks like you are using Realm JS v0.15.4 which was released in January 2017. Please try a recent version.

Comment: Thanks issue resolved